# not show icon when using the materilalup icon

Tags: material-design, materialize, material-ui

when u using this code

`<div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_prefix">First Name</label>
        </div>`

[image]

it not show me icon . why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kianoush add the below link tag

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```